# Identity matrix confusion

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I have the following vertex shader:

```c
attribute vec4 Position;
attribute vec4 SourceColor;
varying vec4 DestinationColor;
uniform mat4 Projection;

void main(void) {
    DestinationColor = SourceColor;
    gl_Position = Projection * Position;
}
```

I then try to apply the following matrix to the `Projection` uniform:

```c
float matrix[16] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionSlot, 1, GL_FALSE, matrix);
```

Shouldn't this do nothing? After running this, I can't see my objects on the screen anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should be a no-op. If you remove the projection multiply then you say it works fine? 
Couple ideas:

- Check glGetError
- Check shader compile/link status (glGetShader/Programiv)
- Is the program bound during glUniform call?
- Is projectionSlot a valid value?

Comment: `glGetError()` returns 0. The program has been compiled and linked before calling `glUniformMatrix4fv()` and `projectionSlot = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "Projection");`. What do you mean with "is the program bound during glUniform call"?

Comment: @Radu: Should be "glGetUniformLocation", not Attrib

Comment: Changed to `glGetUniformLocation()`, still the same issue.

Comment: @Radu Can you put up the complete code that contains everything about shader/initialization?

Comment: @Radu: "What do you mean with "is the program bound during glUniform call"?" I mean you have to call glUseProgram before glUniform (otherwise it doesn't know which program you're affecting, notice the program ID is not a variable to glUniform).

Comment: Thanks for the check list! It's working now, the problem was elsewhere.

Comment: @Radu Just curious, where was the problem? Was it an OpenGL state misconfiguration?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used matrices in programming, but I've taken lot's of math courses. Don't know how the Projection you're using works, but keep in mind the projection of x onto y is very different than projection of y onto x. Try switching them around if you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found a solution.
For me, the problem was resolving the "Projection" variable using `glGetAttribLocation` instead of `glGetUniformLocation`